# Mariadb container still binding port 3306 instead of 3310

Tags: docker, mariadb, port

I'm trying to have multiple MariaDB Docker containers on my server.
First is using 3307 -> 3306 port
Secondary is using 3311 -> 3310 port

But, for the second, docker still binding the 3306 port...

Docker Compose :

```
version:  '3.7'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: ${MARIADB_VERSION}
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - ${PORTS_MARIADB}
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql'
    container_name: ${DB_CONTAINER_NAME}
    networks:
      - network
networks:
  network:
    name: ${NETWORK}
volumes:
  db:
```

.env.prod (only db part):

```
DB_VERSION=mariadb-10.6.4
MARIADB_VERSION=mariadb:10.6.4
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=fzefzfezfze
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_USER=db
MYSQL_PASSWORD=fzefzezfefze
PORTS_MARIADB=3311:3310
```

Docker container ls :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                                                      NAMES
81849c7db9f8   mariadb:10.6.4              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3311->3310/tcp, :::3311->3310/tcp                        db_prod
```

Is there a way to "unbind" this port?

Thanks

Comment: Inside the container is running in its own network namespace. Multiple containers in different namespaces can all listen on port 3306 internally. If you want multiple mariadb containers in the same network namespace (replicating between them or otherwise), use `--port 3301` or similar as the container cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker Image itself "EXPOSEs" port 3306.
The fact that you bind port 3310 to port 3311 is something different.
If you want the db to be available on port 3310 on the Host, you should use "3310:3306" string.

### Short explaination

In Ports section there are 2 numbers:
"AAAA:BBBB"

#### BBBB

This is the port which is exposed inside the container. The Image-software does something on this port. In case of MariaDB it is always port 3306.

#### AAAA

This is the port on the Host you want opened. And if a request on the Host to that port comes in, it is the same as port BBBB on the Container.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use port 3310 instead of default 3306 for MariaDB, you need to add environment variable `MYSQL_TCP_PORT` to your docker compose file:

```
environment:
  ...
  MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3310
```